# Vectorizing an if/then formula comparing value against previous two values; tried np.where()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have rows in my dataframe like below.

```
DateTime        Num1      
6/1/2020 0:33   0.90023
6/1/2020 0:34   0.90022
6/1/2020 0:35   0.90022
6/1/2020 0:38   0.90024
6/1/2020 0:39   0.90025
6/1/2020 0:40   0.90026
```

I am trying to do the below formula vectorized:

```
if (row[0] > row[3]) & (row[0] > row[2]):
     ExpectedResults = 2
elif if (row[0] == row[3]) | (row[0] == row[2]):
     ExpectedResults = 1
elif (row[0] < row[3]) & (row[0] < row[2]):
     ExpectedResults = 0
```

It would result in looking like:

```
DateTime        Num1    ExpectedResult     
6/1/2020 0:33   0.90023       0
6/1/2020 0:34   0.90022       0
6/1/2020 0:35   0.90022       1
6/1/2020 0:38   0.90024       2
6/1/2020 0:39   0.90025       2
6/1/2020 0:40   0.90026       2
```

I tried to use multiple np.where's with multiple conditions, but the result did not line up with manually doing it in excel formulas:

```
df['ExpectedResult'] = np.where( (df['Num1'] > df['Num1'].shift(3)) & (df['Num1'] > df['Num1'].shift(2)),2,
                       np.where( (df['Num1'] == df['Num1'].shift(3)) | (df['Num1'] == df['Num1'].shift(2) ) ,1,
                       np.where( (df['Num1'] < df['Num1'].shift(3)) & (df['Num1'] < df['Num1'].shift(2) ),0,np.nan)))
```

But the above formula is giving me this result:

```
DateTime        Num1    ExpectedResult     np.where
6/1/2020 0:33   0.90023       0               0
6/1/2020 0:34   0.90022       0               0
6/1/2020 0:35   0.90022       1               0
6/1/2020 0:38   0.90024       2               2
6/1/2020 0:39   0.90025       2               2
6/1/2020 0:40   0.90024       1               2
```

The problem with the np.where formula is when the transition happens from 0 to 1 or 1 to 2 or the reverse.  In the example, above when the transition from 0 to 1, it stays at 0 and then jumps to 2.  When it transitions from 2 to 1, it stays at 2 and then jumps to 0.

I also tried just in case it was the axises, but it output the same as previous formula:

```
df['ExpectedResult'] = np.where( (df['Num1'].gt(df['Num1'].shift(3),axis=0)) & (df['Num1'].gt(df['Num1'].shift(2),axis=0)),2,
                        np.where( (df['Num1'].eq(df['Num1'].shift(3),axis=0)) | (df['Num1'].eq(df['Num1'].shift(2),axis=0)) ,1,
                        np.where( (df['Num1'].lt(df['Num1'].shift(3),axis=0)) & (df['Num1'].lt(df['Num1'].shift(2),axis=0) ),0,np.nan)))
```

How can I do the above formula vectorized properly?

Comment: Also note that among the 9 possible combinations of comparisons, you're missing 2 (> & <)

Comment: Your if version condition part 2 is not similar to the same in the vectorized version. –

Comment: And can you justify why the fourth output is 2?

Comment: For my purposes, < and > is not required.  The 4th output is 2, because 90024 is greater than both previous numbers:  90022 and 90022.  An to your second comment, thanks for pointing out the mistake; it gave me a chance to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in the shift().  I had my shifts with wrong numbers.  So by changing my formula to the below worked:

```
df['ExpectedResult'] = np.where( (df['Num1'] > df['Num1'].shift()) & (df['Num1'] > df['Num1'].shift(2)),2,
                       np.where( (df['Num1'] == df['Num1'].shift()) | (df['Num1'] == df['Num1'].shift(2) ) ,1,
                       np.where( (df['Num1'] < df['Num1'].shift()) & (df['Num1'] < df['Num1'].shift(2) ),0,np.nan)))
```